# does 'insert where not exists' include records which inserted at the same insert

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-insert, not-exists

table 1 - id, name, address, item, date, price, ...

table 2 - id, name, item

table 2 cannot have duplicate rows (while table 1 may have some).

by using 'insert where not exists' does its included rows which inserted at that insert itself ?

```
insert into table2 (id,name,item)
select id, name, item
from table1
where not exists 
(select 1 from table2 where table2.id=table1.id and table2.name=table1.name and table2.item=table1.item)
```

Comment: No, as the rows don't exist in the table at the time you run the `INSERT`. You can easily see this if you run a couple of simple tests. :)

Answer (score 2):

No.  This can be handled using `select distinct`:

```
insert into table2 (id, name, item)
    select distinct id, name, item
    from table1
    where not exists 
    (select 1 from table2 where table2.id=table1.id and table2.name=table1.name and table2.item=table1.item) ;
```

Comment: TY! by using "select distinct id, name, item" its mean all the 3 at the same row?or each one individual?

Comment: @rotem it applies to all 3 columns. `1, 'foo', 'bar'` is a different row from `1, 'foo', 'blat'`. If you have a specific column or set of columns that need to be unique, say so in your question, instead of just saying "rows" - we have no idea how you've defined your keys in either of these tables.